# Meteor-Files intergration with google storage block prevent publish users

Tags: mongodb, meteor, google-cloud-storage

I have Meteor-React app locally, I added Meteor file with the integration of Google Cloud storage from this guide:

https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/docs/google-cloud-storage-integration.md

As Google changed documentation I follow this NPM package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage

then I follow this link and create a key-file
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create#--iam-account

and finally created a bucket:

```
 gcs = new Storage({keyFilename: 
`${Meteor.rootPath}/assets/app/gntapp-3fb3c-storage.json`})
```

and activated from gcloud terminal :

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file [KEY_FILE]
```

I uploaded the first image in storage.

now my problem is **My users' publication does not work** and users not publish.

when I do:

```
console.log(Meteor.users.find({}).fetch())
```

in Meteor.Startup I got information of bucket *kind: 'storage#bucket'*

but login with username and password work as normal.

can anybody help me to figure out the issue?

I use `METEOR@1.8.1`

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is here - is it just that some users publication (which you don't provide code for) doesn't work? Meteor.users is a "special" collection. For security reasons it doesn't behave like a normal collection

Comment: "does not work" isn't something we can help you diagnose. Please provide logs, error messages, etc.

Comment: Can you please show the user publication? By default there is only the current logged in user published to the client. Other users have to be published explicitly.